# How to use onClickListener when the buttons are in different layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, onclicklistener

I'm trying to use onClickListener but I keep getting Null exceptions.

This is the call to onClickListener -

```
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                      // code here

            }
        }
    };

    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

'button1' is found on a **different layout** which opens (as a Dialog) when the user press on some other button.

What can I do to in this case?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to inflate the layout with the dialogue's buttons.
for example, this is my method for displaying a popup.

I have named the method showPopup;

```
Dialogue ViewSview_student_dialogue;
view_student_dialogue = new Dialogue(getApplicationContext());

private void showStudentPopup(String name,String id_gender) {
        TextView cancelpopup,st_name,id_and_gender;
        view_student_dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.custom_student_popup);
        cancelpopup = (TextView)view_student_dialogue.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        st_name = (TextView)view_student_dialogue.findViewById(R.id.st_name);
        id_and_gender = (TextView)view_student_dialogue.findViewById(R.id.id_and_gender);

        st_name.setText(name);
        id_and_gender.setText(id_gender);

        cancelpopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view_student_dialogue.dismiss();
            }
        });
        view_student_dialogue.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));
        view_student_dialogue.show();
    }
```

Please take note that custom_student_popup is a layout file that i have created in the res layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout inflator to inflate that view first then set listener.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to get a reference to the view for your `Dialog`.

First, you inflate the xml layout for your `Dialog`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
```

You then set that as the view for your new `Dialog`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(dialogLayout);
```

You can then get a reference to the `Button` from the inflated `View` and set you `OnClickListener`:

```
Button yourButton = (Button)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
/// do the click listener assignment
```

Show your `Dialog` to the user:

```
builder.show();
```